# Alternative to ASP.Net Cache Options

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, caching

Is there a way to store and get Large amount of data on search function or page load without using ASP.Net Caching options ?

The `ASP.NET` `Cache options` might not be the best options to use for those contents that are constantly updating.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store data in a session variable and set the ASP.NET application to store session data in a SQL Server database.

[HOW TO: Configure SQL Server to Store ASP.NET Session State](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317604)

Comment: But how much data would be better to save in session. when it need to be available for search purposes.